# Contact Form 7 SMS integration with twilio

Tags: wordpress, sms, contact-form-7

How do I setup so that I can send out SMS whenever someone has fill in the form? I'm using https://www.twilio.com for the sms. 
Where do I include the actions in contact form 7 when submitting form? Appreciate any help here, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook yourself in to the CF 7 process.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203043/extending-contact-form-7-wordpress-plugin-by-using-hooks), [here](http://club.orbisius.com/howto/web-development/hook-contact-form-7-wordpress-plugin-sending-email/) and [here](http://xaviesteve.com/3298/wordpress-contact-form-7-hook-unofficial-developer-documentation-and-examples/) for more information and some examples on how to do it.

Hooking into where/after the mail is sent might be interesting for what you want to do.

Comment: so basically what i need to do is to create a hook before the contact form submit & den include the api code from there? correct me if I'm getting the concept wrong... thanks.

Comment: No, you got the concept right but you should think about where to hook in. If you want to be notified about sent forms you should have a look for a hook that is triggered, when the form was successfully sent.

Answer (score 2):

Got it right with this 1, now what's left is trying to echo the information submitted to the sms message. Can i use echo directly?

Noticed this on filter changes as well, not sure it this affected http://contactform7.com/2015/05/18/contact-form-7-42-beta/

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function' );

function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function() {
   // Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
   require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

   $account_sid = 'AC914e20c15791698c1d86cfc297e30f64'; 
   $auth_token = '1e962df32508157599929e545033c869'; 
   $client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 

   $client->account->messages->create(array( 
       'To' => "+60167833549", 
       'From' => "+13479604387", 
       'Body' => "form submited",   
   ));
```

}

Comment: That looks good. I am not sure how or if it is possible at all to output information to the form again.

Comment: If that's you real auth token then you should probably delete it and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

please use this WordPress plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-sms-api/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a free plugin for sms notifications from wordpress contact form 7:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-international-sms-integration/

You can configure this plugin with any sms Gateway SMS API Ex. Spring Edge.